# CS193P, runProgram and Assignment 2

Tags: objective-c

I'm working on assignment 2 of CS193P - Stanford's IOS programming course. One thing I was wondering about is how the calculatorBrain is supposed to be able to accept and run a stored program, a program being an array or stack of operands and operations.

So let's say we want to perform the following calculation: 2, 3, 4, +, *

If you typed this into the calulator, the following would happen:

2 3 4 get pushed onto the stack one at a time, and runProgram called for each one, which simply pops the number off the stack and returns it's value which gets pushed onto the stack.
You press +, and runProgram pops this and sees it has to add the top 2 items which it does and pushes the result onto the stack which now contains 2, 7. You press * and the stack now contains 14.

But I can't see how you can pass an array containing (2, 3, 4, +, `*`) to the brain (the instructor says later you can just pass a program to the runProgram class method and get the result, without having to instantiate a brain object), as runProgram would first try to execute the top operand i.e. `*` and to do this it would take the next two objects off the stack and try to multiply them and to push the result back onto the stack. These 2 objects are "+" and "4" which won't work.

Now the instructor has been doing this a lot longer than I have, as I assume that I'm missing somethings, but I'm not sure what.

Any ideas?

Comment: You do realise most people reading this question aren't attending the same course you are. You'll have to provide more context.

Comment: @Inerdial - looks like the OP is 'attending' the Stanford U iOS classes. Making his question *somewhat* similar to a Project Eulers question.

Comment: @Perception Then that piece of information would've been the necessary context.

Comment: @Inerdial - the OP could stand to add an introductory sentence, yes. As it is, the primary indication is in the description of the cs193p tag.

Comment: Sorry guys - should have elaborated that this was connected to CS193P - Stanford's IOS programming course, and is really only aimed at, or of interest to, others doing the course, due to the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - the answer is that the way runProgram gets the next item off the stack is by recursively calling a popOperandOffStack (pOOS) method.

So when it gets passed a program consisting of 2 3 4 + *, it starts by popping * off the stack. It then has to pop the next two operands off the stack. So it calls pOOS, which firstly returns a '+', so it then calls pOOS again (twice) which gets '4' & '3' respectively, which are added to get 7 which is pushed back onto the stack (which now contains 2 7) and also returned as the result of calling pOOS. So when it called pOOS for the first operand of the '*' operation it didn't get '+', it actually got '7'. The second call to pOOS (for the second operand of the *) gets '2' which it then happily multiplies to get 14.

I did try looking up recursion in my IT dictionary, but it just said 'See recursion'.

Comment: Credit for this goes to David Barton on another site. I kept think of the pOOS method as just getting an operand, forgetting that it called itself. Never made any use of recursion myself in my career.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at this as passing "2,3,4,+,*" to the "brain", you need to be thinking in the context of the stack processor.

The arguments are evaluated in the order in which they are encountered in the array.   But, don't confuse the array for the stack, they are different objects.   The stack is internal to the calculator routine and the array of input is external to the routine.  Since I'm not taking that particular class at whatever school you're in, I can't speak to the particulars of the language in use, but basically, think of the array "2,3,4,+,*" as input to the keyboard of the calculator.   However, the calculator is a very simple machine and only processes one key press at a time.

Thus, when you process the array, you're basically passing each element of the array to the calculator for processing and the calculator is then deciding whether to push to the stack or execute the operator.   These elements are passed in order, so the calculator receives: 2 followed by 3, followed by 4, followed by '+', followed by '*'.

It looks like you're trying to think of the problem in terms of the array being passed in to the calculator as the stack, and that's not what you want to do here.

I hope this is clear.

Comment: gaige - I think I know what you mean: It seems to me that runProgram should really take the passed stack, and start at the bottom, popping things off and pushing them onto a new stack, which it executes as before. This simulates a user entering the operations and operands. But the instructor is quite clear that it doesn't work like this. It might well be that the functionality he's alluding to just never gets implemented, and so my confusion is understandable. I think I'll just roll with it for now :-)

Answer (score 0):

@steve Ives, I think you nailed the answer with this last comment. Having gone through this assignment a few weeks back (also on my own), I found this site to be helpful understanding the reverse polish calculator, it basically emulates one. But as you are thinking recursion, your brain can go into overload mode. Hope this helps validating some of your scenario testing...Good luck.
[HP12C Emulator](http://www.epx.com.br/ctb/hp12c.php)